# Unable to import JSON file into a Python file

Tags: python, json

I am working on a dictionary project. So, I downloaded a JSON file and ***placed it on my desktop***. I tried to import it into my Python file but it says the file is not found.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'
```

Here's my code:

```
import json

data = json.loads(open('data.json'))
print(data)
```

Comment: For code to work, your python code should also be on Desktop folder. Please check if it is so.

Comment: where is your python script file placed?

Comment: adding to @gautamits the open('data.json') accepts complete path of the json file so you may also provide absolute path of json file regardles of where your code is located.

Comment: Yes @PavanKumarTS, thanks for clarifying, that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to get the home directory of the current user and then using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) you can obtain the full path to `data.json` located in `Desktop` directory.

Use:

```
import os
import json

filepath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "data.json") 
with open(filepath) as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    print(data)
```

Comment: @HenryWoody Not required. I've used `json.load `instead of `json.loads`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. (For future reference, I'd left a comment saying that `file.read()` was possibly required)